# Sending Ctrl+break sequence through Plink

Tags: c#, shell, ssh, putty, plink

I am trying to automate the remote server shell commands through Plink. And one of the things which I did is `grep` command.

Now suppose if results lots of data then I just want to break the command.

Generally from PuTTY you just do <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl-Break</kbd> and it will break the command.

What's the alternative for Plink?

Answer (score 0):

Do not run Plink from C# application to implement SSH. Use a native .NET implementation of SSH, like [SSH.NET](https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET). – It will give you a complete control over the connection and you won't have have to use *hacks* like sending <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>.

```cs
var client = new SshClient("example.com", "username", "password");
client.Connect();

SshCommand command = client.CreateCommand("grep pattern file");
IAsyncResult result = command.BeginExecute();
using (var outputReader = new StreamReader(command.OutputStream))
using (var extendedReader = new StreamReader(command.ExtendedOutputStream))
{
    int read = 0;
    while (read < 10240)
    {
        string s;
        s = outputReader.ReadToEnd();
        read += s.Length;
        Console.Write(s);
        s = extendedReader.ReadToEnd();
        read += s.Length;
        Console.Write(s);
    }
}

command.CancelAsync();
```

---

Also, you can use `-m` switch to stop [`grep`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/grep.1.html) after certain number of matches.